# React Native 'ERROR TypeError: Cannot convert undefined value to object'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to retrieve data in this way:

```js
    useEffect(() => {
      async function fetchData() {
        const response = await fetch('https://hasanadiguzel.com.tr/api/kurgetir');
        const json = await response.json();
        setData(json);
      }
      fetchData();
    }, []);
console.log(data.TCMB_AnlikKurBilgileri[0].Isim);
```

When I run `console.log(data.TCMB_AnlikKurBilgileri);` upon opening the application, the API seems to be working fine and the data is being retrieved. However, when I try to retrieve `data.TCMB_AnlikKurBilgileri[0].Isim` with `console.log(data.TCMB_AnlikKurBilgileri[0].Isim);`, I get the error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot convert undefined value to object`.
But, when I save the application after running `console.log(data.TCMB_AnlikKurBilgileri);` and then run `console.log(data.TCMB_AnlikKurBilgileri[0].Isim);`, it works without any problems and gives the output.

How can I solve this issue? note: You can watch the video to better understand my problem https://youtu.be/x_mlvMDzUt4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to console.log outside of useEffect. It cause the problem since your api did not fetch data yet, but you are trying to log data.

So, move your console.log inside of useEffect to check api response is correct.

```
const json = await response.json();
console.log(json.TCMB_AnlikKurBilgileri[0].Isim);
setData(json);
```

At first when you render the component, data has no any value(so maybe undefined) if you did not set initial value. Once api request done and updated state with response, your UI will updated with correct value.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign an object to an array. `data` is array and `json` is an object.

Instead of empty array use `null` as default value:

```
const [data, setData] = useState(null)
```

In order to track data changes you should also add a separate useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
 console.log(data?.TCMB_AnlikKurBilgileri[0]?.Isim)
},[data])
```

Comment: ```const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const response = await fetch('https://hasanadiguzel.com.tr/api/kurgetir');
      const json = await response.json();
      setData(json);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(data?.TCMB_AnlikKurBilgileri[0]?.Isim);
}, [data]);
```

The final version of the code looks like this and it gives the following error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot convert undefined value to object`

Comment: here is the response data: https://i.hizliresim.com/sz40rgi.jpg